# Using DeMorgan's Laws to complement a function

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Using DeMorgan's Law, write an expression for the complement of $F$ if:

1. **$F(x,y,z) = x(y' + z)$.**

   $F=x'+(y'+x)'$
2. **$F(x,y,z) = xy + x'z + yz'$**

   $F=(xy)'(x'z)'(yz')'$
3. **$F(w,x,y,z) = xyz' (y'z + x)' + (w'yz + x' )$.**

   $F=[(xyz')'+(y'z+x)](w'yz+x')'$

My answers are underneath the numbered questions. Is everything correct? I'm not 100% sure as to what I'm exactly supposed to do. I just took all the ANDs, negated them and made them ORs and vice-versa.

Comment: Does the problem ask us to *just* use some "De Morgan" law(s) or ask us to simplify as much as possible?  In other words, can we use other laws, or only the equivalences given which get called "De Morgan" laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to stop there. Continue using De Morgan until you get to these simpler forms.

1. $F^c = x' + y z'$
2. $F^c = (x'+y')(x + z')(y'+z)$
3. $F^c = x(w+y' +z')$

---

Since you asked, let me briefly explain how I got (3). At some point during the reduction you will come across a long formula like this:

$((x' + y' + z) + (y'z + x))((w + y' + z')x)$

Now, noticing that disjunction (+) is associative we can collapse the parens on the left to get:

$(x' + y' + z + y'z + x)((w + y' + z')x)$

And here we immediately realize that we're dealing with the tautology $(x + x')$:

$(\color{blue}{x' +} y' + z + y'z + \color{blue}{x})((w + y' + z')x)$

This means that the entire formula on the left is materially equivalent ($\equiv$) to $\top$:

$\color{blue}{\top}((w + y' + z')x)$

Now since $(\top \land \phi) \equiv \phi$, for all $\phi$, we cancel it, getting:

$(w + y' + z')x$

Lastly, since conjunction is commutative, I just put the x in front to obtain:

$x(w + y' + z')$

Comment: How'd you get the last one?

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll explain the trick under my answer.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks again!

Comment: "Now, noticing that disjunction (+) is associative we can collapse the parens on the left to get"  But you've used more than a "De Morgan" Law.  Does the problem ask us to just use some "De Morgan" law(s) or ask us to simplify as much as possible?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear about the rules of logic, Demorgan's Laws dictate the following:

$(ab)' = a' + b' \\
(a+b)' = a'b'$

The mnemonic that helps me remember Demorgan's Laws: "Break the negation/complement line, change the sign." Note that a complement of a complement (double apostrophes) is just the original argument. I.e., $(a')' = a'' = a$

1. $F = x(y'+z) \\ F' = [x(y'+z)]' \\ = x' + [y'+z]' \\ = x'+ y''z' \\ = x'+yz'$
2. $F = xy+x'z+yz' \\ F'= [xy+x'z+yz']' = [(xy+x'z)+(yz')]' = (xy+x'z)'(yz')' \\ = [(xy)+(x'z)]'[y'+z'']  = (xy)'(x'z)'[y'+z]  =(x'+y')(x''+z')(y'+z) \\ = (x'+y')(x+z')(y'+z) \\ = [x'x+x'z'+xy'+y'z'](y'+z) \\ =[0+x'z'+xy'+y'z'](y'+z) \\ = x'y'z'+x'z'z+xy'y'+xy'z+y'y'z'+y'z'z \\ = x'y'z'+x'(0)+x(y')+xy'z+(y')z'+y'(0) \\ = x'y'z'+xy'+xy'z+y'z' \\ F' = y'(x'z'+x+xz+z')$
3. $F = xyz' (y'z + x)' + (w'yz + x' ) \\ F' = [xyz' (y'z + x)' + (w'yz + x' )]' = [xyz'(y'z+x)']'[(w'yz+x')]' \\ = [[xyz']'+[x+y'z]'][[w'yz]'[x']'] = [(x'+y'+z'')+x'(y'z')'][(w''+y'+z')x'' \\ = [x'+y'+z+x'(y''+z'')][x(w+y'+z')]\\ = x(x'+y'+z+x'y+x'z)(w+y'+z') \\ = (xx'+xy'+xz+xx'y+xx'z)(w+y'+z') \\ = (0+xy'+xz+0)(w+y'+z') \\ = wxy'+xy'y'+xy'z'+wxz+xy'z+xzz' \\ = wxy'+x(1)+xy'z'+wxz+xy'z+x(0) \\ F'= wxy'+x+xy'z'+wxz+xy'z$

Comment: "Note that a complement of a complement (double apostrophes) is just the original argument. I.e., (a ′ ) ′ =a ′′ =a "  But that's not a "De Morgan" Law.  Does the problem ask us to just use some "De Morgan" law(s) or ask us to simplify as much as possible?

Comment: I  wanted to make sure people understood  what was going on when i expanded the complement so they wouldn't be confused when x" became x. No this is not a De Morgan law but simply a general rule of logic to help illustrate my simplification of F'